# Book about a boy travelling space in a bubble; he has a translation earpiece

Tags: story-identification, books

The librarian at my school read us a book in the late 1990s/early 2000s about a boy who finds a bubble that he can travel through space in.  He visits other planets.  The only other things I remember about it was they had earpieces that automatically translated alien languages.

It was quite long as she would read a chapter every time we went to library.  She also read us *The Hobbit* that year.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark byt the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

Could it be *[Mad Queen of Mordra](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/5749157-the-mad-queen-of-mordra)*, aka *Billy and the Bubbleship*, by Elwy Yost?

> Hovering before him was an enormous bubble, taller even than he was, and faintly shimmering with an unearthly light.
>
> Billy Brown can't resist the opportunity to experiment with the mysterious substance he has found. Before he knows it, he's whisked far into space, through a black hole to a strange flat planet. Soon he's embroiled in a deadly game of chess with an evil mad queen. Can Billy beat her, or will he and his friends be devoured by a monster too hideous for words?

[This review](https://file:///C:/Users/sean.duggan/Downloads/1755-Article%20Text-1336-1-10-20090302.pdf) mentions the translation devices.

> There are ice-guns which freeze people (or unfreeze them),
> and crystals which provide a simultaneous translation service, but the pace
> is so fast that the reader is already taking a new wonder for granted before
> there is time to question the plausibility of the last one.

It was the answer to [this TOMT Reddit question](https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/lkw5a6/tomtpre90s_kids_novel_boy_rides_an_alien_bubble/), which I found with a search for
`1990s novel boy bubble space`

Comment: Is it _the_ Elwy Yost?  I had no idea he'd written anything.

Comment: @DavidW: Perhaps? https://www.goodreads.com/author/show/1864553.Elwy_Yost

Comment: Wow, [it is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elwy_Yost)!  Note that [ISFDb](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2615643) gives the book's title as *Billy & the Bubbleship*.

Comment: Thank you. That helps explain why I found so few references when searching for mention of the translation device. :-D